# Adding sections and web parts to the modern pages is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

@pnp/sp version is 1.2.3/1.2.7
SharePoint version is SPO (online)

I am loading the site in the Web object and adding the client side page using the web object. Once the page got created I am adding sections, columns & web parts to the page, finally I am saving the page. The created page was holding the sections and web parts which was added programmatically, but all of sudden the sections and the web parts not appearing. I am not getting any errors but the sections are not getting added for the newly created pages.

The code I am using for creating page and adding web parts:

```
(async () => { 
var web = new Web("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test"); 
const page = await web.addClientSidePage("test.aspx", "My site Page"); 
const section = page.addSection(); 
const column = section.addColumn(4); 
const column1 = section.addColumn(4); 
const column2 = section.addColumn(4); 
await page.save(); 
})().then(_ => { }).catch( error => console.log(error) );
```

Could anyone please help me with any suggestion/solution. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit late but updating @pnp/sp version to 1.3 or greater solved the issue for me

Comment: Yes Joy. It was pnp issue, so I ve raised an issue in Github https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/504.